# Knockout JS: ko.applyBindings is not a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to use Knockout js in a simple web application.
Here's my dummy javascript code:

```
function MainViewModel() {
    this.myText = ko.observable('Hello world');
}
var MainViewModelInstance = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(MainViewModelInstance);
```

But when I run the index.html, the debug console says "ko.applyBindings is not a function"!

Help!
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have not included the link to the knockout.js library in your source code or the link is wrong. Fix this and it will work.

```html
<script src="/scripts/knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Where the /scripts directory is the location on the server where knockoutjs resides.

EDIT

Here is an example of your code that works.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function MainViewModel() {
                this.myText = ko.observable('Hello world');
            }
            var MainViewModelInstance = new MainViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(MainViewModelInstance);

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sure that I included the library and the path is correct. Indeed, if I comment tha last line where I call applyBindings(), there's no errors in the second line, where I call ko.observable(). Why?!?!

Comment: The call to ko.observable is not executed because the MainViewModel function is not executed. This is why there is no error when you comment out that line.

Comment: Turns out that the javascript engine of the browser can't recognize the call "document.createComment()" as a javascript function. I commented that call in the Knockout Js and now everything works... So weird!